# How to avoid SCAN while filtering on a marketplace app using Dynamodb?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

**Problem description**: The app provides a list of products which can be purchased at some price and I want customers to be able to filter through **all items** by `asking-price` or `estimated-value`

**Sample attributes**: `asking-price, posted-by, product-id, estimated-value, status.`
(status being available or sold)

**Sample Data**:
`$10.00, fredflinstone@email.com, 1234, $12.00`

I thought of using approach 1:

- one GSI with `product-id` as the partition key and `asking-price` as sort key
- one GSI with `product-id` as the partition key and `estimated-value` as  sort key

*but the problem with this is that we don't know the partition key since we are looking through all items.*

I also though of approach 2:

- one GSI with `status` as the partition key and `asking-price` as sort key
- one GSI with `status` as the partition key and `estimated-value` as  sort key

*but the problem is that the products are no longer unique*

Lastly, I tried approach 3:

- one GSI with `status` as the partition key and `asking-price#product-id` as sort key
- one GSI with `status` as the partition key and `estimated-value#product-id` as  sort key

*but the problem here is that the greater than / less than conditions don't return accurate results since the sort key is now a string*

It seems that the only answer left is to use SCANS with filterexpressions however I'm concerned with the costs of having a SCAN feature in the critical path of the application. Is there anyway around this? If not, would you recommend limits, max items, or parallel scans to improve performance? Should I go to a Relational DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GSI approach 2 will work, items in a GSI do not need to be unique.

The only thing you need to be mindful of is using a low cardinality key (status). This would limit the throughput on your table. Each status would essentially be capped at 1000 WCU and 3000 RCU as that is the limit of a single partition.

If you need more throughput than that, then I would suggest using random numbers 0-N for your partition key. If you need to write at 10k WCU per second, then use random numbers 0-9 for the GSI PK. When you need to read, just run 10 parallel queries for each one of the keys.

Comment: As Lee said, there is an example in AWS docs that duplicate your case https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.scenario

Comment: Thank you both so much. I can't believe I didn't read about this feature while I was researching, would have saved me some time!.